# Can I add a "Like" Button in Twitter's Bootstrap Popover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a button which launches a popover when clicked (just like the live demo here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)

Now I would like a simple like button in the content field of the popover. Is that possible? Currently, the popover does display only the link as text "http://test.com"

Currently:

```
<a href="#" id="example" rel="popover" data-content="http://test.com" data-original-title="Like"><img src="img/specialbutton.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not completly sure what you mean with a like-button. In order to place a button with the anchortext "like" and a link to "http://test.com" on the popover :

1 Remove all data-xxx references from your `<a>`-tag

```
<a href="#" id="example" rel="popover"><img src="img/specialbutton.png"></a>
```

2 invoke the popover like this

```
$('#example').popover({
  placement: 'right',
  title: 'Like this website?',
  html: true,
  content: '<button class="btn"><a href="http://test.com">Like</a></button>'
});
```

You can place many types of HTML-tags in `content`, maybe you want a gruop of buttons to various social media? If you want to add a facebook-button you must follow the [guidelines](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) for this and insert the code generated from there in content

Comment: @davidkonrad how we can get the above button click event in jquery?